# Efficiently select elements from an (x,y) field with a 2D mask in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large field of 2D-position data, given as two arrays `x` and `y`, where `len(x) == len(y)`.  I would like to return the array of indices `idx_masked` at which `(x[idx_masked], y[idx_masked])` is masked by an N x N `int` array called `mask`. That is, `mask[x[idx_masked], y[idx_masked]] == 1`. The `mask` array consists of `0`s and `1`s only.

I have come up with the following solution, but it (specifically, the last line below) is very slow, given that I have N x N = 5000 x 5000, repeated 1000s of times:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example mask of one corner of a square
N = 100
mask = np.zeros((N, N))
mask[0:10, 0:10] = 1

# example x and y position arrays in arbitrary units
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)

x_bins = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), N)
y_bins = np.linspace(np.min(y), np.max(y), N)

x_bin_idx = np.digitize(x, x_bins)
y_bin_idx = np.digitize(y, y_bins)

idx_masked = np.ravel(np.where(mask[y_bin_idx - 1, x_bin_idx - 1] == 1))

plt.imshow(mask[::-1, :])
```

[image: the mask itself]

```
plt.scatter(x, y, color='red')
plt.scatter(x[idx_masked], y[idx_masked], color='blue')
```

[image: the masked particle field]

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Can you show a runnable example? I don't have `x`, `y` and `mask` to work with. Could you also explain in words what you think your example is doing?

Comment: are you trying to get x and y where mask==1 ?,  is mask has the same shape of x and y ?

Comment: @AlyHosny, no mask does not have the same shape as x and y.

Comment: @MadPhysicist In words: if I bin `x` and `y` into the shape of `mask`, which `x` and `y` fall on elements of `mask` that are equal to 1?

Comment: @MadPhysicist that is, the only thing that matters is the shape of `mask`, not the actual position of its bins in the "position space" of (x,y)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'll edit the question to make it reproducible

Comment: For starters. I don't think you need `x_bin_idx = np.digitize(x, x_bins)`. You can just do `x_bin_idx = (N * (x - x.min())) // (x.max() - x.min())`

Comment: Would you consider having `idx_masked` be a boolean mask of the same size as `x`, `y`? It might be more efficient that way.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm only worried about the `np.where()` line: the others are fast-enough. Why would a boolean be faster?

Comment: The np.where is indeed your bottleneck. Re-implement np.where for your case using numba, and it is lightning fast.

Comment: `mask[y_bin_idx - 1, x_bin_idx - 1] == 1` is your mask. You can apply it to `x`, `y`. You can get the indices with `np.flatnonzero` if you have to, by why bother? You can also represent it as `mask[y_bin_idx - 1, x_bin_idx - 1].astype(bool)`.

Comment: The line `idx_masked = np.ravel(np.where(mask[y_bin_idx-1, x_bin_idx-1]==1))` could be simplified to `idx_masked = mask[y_bin_idx-1, x_bin_idx-1].nonzero()[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `mask` overlays your field with identically-sized bins, you do not need to define the bins explicitly. `*_bin_idx` can be determined at each location from a simple floor division, since you know that each bin is `1 / N` in size. I would recommend using `1 - 0` for the total width (what you passed into `np.random.uniform`) instead of `x.max() - x.min()`, if of course you know the expected size of the range.

```
x0 = 0   # or x.min()
x1 = 1   # or x.max()
x_bin = (x1 - x0) / N
x_bin_idx = ((x - x0) // x_bin).astype(int)

# ditto for y
```

This will be faster and simpler than digitizing, and avoids the extra bin at the beginning.

For most purposes, you do not need `np.where`. 90% of the questions asking about it (including this one) should not be using `where`. If you want a fast way to access the necessary elements of `x` and `y`, just use a boolean mask. The mask is simply

```
selction = mask[x_bin_idx, y_bin_idx].astype(bool)
```

If `mask` is already a boolean (which it should be anyway), the expression `mask[x_bin_idx, y_bin_idx]` is sufficient. It results in an array of the same size as `x_bin_idx` and `y_bin_idx` (which are the same size as `x` and `y`) containing the mask value for each of your points. You can use the mask as

```
x[selection]   # Elements of x in mask
y[selection]   # Elements of y in mask
```

If you absolutely need the integer indices, `where` is sill not your best option.

```
indices = np.flatnonzero(selection)
```

OR

```
indices = selection.nonzero()[0]
```

If your goal is simply to extract values from `x` and `y`, I would recommend stacking them together into a single array:

```
coords = np.stack((x, y), axis=1)
```

This way, instead of having to apply indices twice, you can extract the values with just

```
coords[selection, :]
```

OR

```
coords[indices, :]
```

Depending on the relative densities of `mask` and `x` and `y`, either the boolean masking or linear indexing may be faster. You will have to time some relevant cases to get a better intuition.

Comment: Unless a large fraction of the mask's elements are non-zero, then it's faster to compute the `nonzero` indices since they are used to index into two different arrays `x` and `y`. Otherwise there a two loops running through an almost-empty mask.

Comment: @a_guest. It's really just one loop, but I see your point. That loop still needs to run to compute `nonzero` or equivalent. The question then becomes one of how the info will be used. If the index is applied once, it is faster to stick with boolean. If more than once than *maybe* the linear indices are worthwhile to compute.

Comment: There is a type issue: `x_bin_idx` is an array of floats (in python 3) which cannot be used for indexing.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I just tested with `a = np.arange(1_000_000)` and `m = np.random.random(size=len(a)) < 0.5` and it's significantly faster to first compute `i = m.nonzero()[0]` and then do `a[i], a[i]` as opposed to `a[m], a[m]`. At about `m.sum() / len(m) >= 0.9` the timings become equal. Using a boolean mask, I suppose numpy first needs to sum the mask in order to determine the size of the output array, then loop another time to fill it. For an index array the output size is simply `len(i)` so it needs to loop only once.

Comment: @Haydon. Thanks for the catch. A faster alternative than the `astype(int)` I added is it to pre-allocate `x_bin_idx` as an array of ints, and call `np.floor_divide(x - x0, x_bin, out=x_bin_idx, cast='unsafe')`

Comment: @a_guest. Thanks for the timing. I've edited the answer to reflect what you said.